# Fuzzy string record search algorithm (supporting word transpose and character transpose)

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic, string-matching

I am trying to find the best algorithm for my particular application.  I have searched around on SO, Google, read various articles about Levenshtein distances, etc. but honestly it's a bit out of my area of expertise.  And most seem to find how similar two input strings are, like a Hamming distance between strings.

What I'm looking for is different, more of a fuzzy record search (and I'm sure there is a name for it, that I don't know to Google).  I am sure someone has solved this problem before and I'm looking for a recommendation to point me in the right direction for my further research.

In my case I am needing a fuzzy search of a database of entries of music artists and their albums.  As you can imagine, the database will have millions of entries so an algorithm that scales well is crucial.  It's not important to my question that Artist and Album are in different columns, the database could just store all words in one column if that helped the search.

**The database to search:**

```
|-------------------|---------------------|
| Artist            | Album               |
|-------------------|---------------------|
| Alanis Morissette | Jagged Little Pill  |
| Moby              | Everything is Wrong |
| Air               | Moon Safari         |
| Pearl Jam         | Ten                 |
| Nirvana           | Nevermind           |
| Radiohead         | OK Computer         |
| Beck              | Odelay              |
|-------------------|---------------------|
```

The query text will contain from just one word in the entire Artist_Album concatenation up to the entire thing.  The query text is coming from OCR and is likely to have single character transpositions but the most likely thing is the words are not guaranteed to have the right order.  Additionally, there could be extra words in the search that aren't a part of the album (like cover art text).  For example, "OK Computer" might be at the top of the album and "Radiohead" below it, or some albums have text arranged in columns which intermixes the word orders.

**Possible search strings:**

```
C0mputer Rad1ohead
Pearl Ten Jan
Alanis Jagged Morisse11e Litt1e Pi11
Air Moon Virgin Records
Moby Everything
```

Note that with OCR, some letters will look like numbers, or the wrong letter completely (Jan instead of Jam). And in the case of Radiohead's *OK Computer* and Moby's *Everything Is Wrong*, the query text doesn't even have all of the words.  In the case of Air's *Moon Safari*, the extra words Virgin Records are searched, but Safari is missing.

Is there a general algorithm that could return the single likeliest result from the database, and if none meet some "likeliness" score threshold, it returns nothing?  I'm actually developing this in Python, but that's just a bonus, I'm looking more for where to get started researching.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the problem down in two parts.

- First, you want to define some measure of likeness (this is called a metric). This metric should return a small number if the query text closely matches the album/artist cover, and return a larger number otherwise.
- Second, you want a datastructure that speeds up this process. Obviously, you don't want to calculate this metric every single time a query is ran.

**part 1: the metric**

You already mentioned Levenshtein distance, which is a great place to start.
Think outside the box though.

LD makes certain assumptions (each character replacement is equally likely, deletion is equally likely as insertion, etc). You can obviously improve the performance of this metric by taking into account what faults OCR is likely to introduce.

E.g. turning a '1' into an 'i' should not be penalized as harshly as turning a '0' into an '_'.

I would implement the metric in two stages. For any given two strings:

- split both strings in tokens (assume space as the separator)
- look for the most similar words (using a modified version of LD)
- assign a final score based on 'matching words', 'missing words' and 'added words' (preferably weighted)

This is an example implementation (fiddle around with the constants):

```
static double m(String a, String b){
    String[] aParts = a.split(" ");
    String[] bParts = b.split(" ");
    boolean[] bUsed = new boolean[bParts.length];
    int matchedTokens = 0;
    int tokensInANotInB = 0;
    int tokensInBNotInA = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<aParts.length;i++){
        String a0 = aParts[i];
        boolean wasMatched = true;
        for(int j=0;j<bParts.length;j++){
            String b0 = bParts[j];
            double d = levenshtein(a0, b0);
            /* If we match the token a0 with a token from b0
             * update the number of matchedTokens
             * escape the loop
             */
            if(d < 2){
                bUsed[j]=true;
                wasMatched = true;
                matchedTokens++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!wasMatched){
            tokensInANotInB++;
        }
    }
    for(boolean partUsed : bUsed){
        if(!partUsed){
            tokensInBNotInA++;
        }
    }
    return (matchedTokens 
    + tokensInANotInB * -0.3  // the query is allowed to contain extra words at minimal cost
    + tokensInBNotInA * -0.5  // the album title should not contain too many extra words
    ) / java.lang.Math.max(aParts.length, bParts.length); 
}
```

This function uses a modified levenshtein function:

```
static double levenshtein(String x, String y) {
double[][] dp = new double[x.length() + 1][y.length() + 1];

for (int i = 0; i <= x.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= y.length(); j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            dp[i][j] = j;
        }
        else if (j == 0) {
            dp[i][j] = i;
        }
        else {
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i - 1][j - 1] 
             + costOfSubstitution(x.charAt(i - 1), y.charAt(j - 1)), 
              dp[i - 1][j] + 1, 
              dp[i][j - 1] + 1);
        }
    }
}
return dp[x.length()][y.length()];
}
```

Which uses the function 'cost of substitution' (which works as explained)

```
static double costOfSubstitution(char a, char b){
    if(a == b)
        return 0.0;
    else{
        // 1 and i
        if(a == '1' && b == 'i')
            return 0.5;
        if(a == 'i' && b == '1')
            return 0.5;

        // 0 and O
        if(a == '0' && b == 'o')
            return 0.5;
        if(a == 'o' && b == '0')
            return 0.5;
        if(a == '0' && b == 'O')
            return 0.5;
        if(a == 'O' && b == '0')
            return 0.5;

        // default
        return 1.0; 
    }
}
```

I only included a couple of examples (turning '1' into 'i' or '0' into 'o').
But I'm sure you get the idea.

**part 2: the datastructure**

Look into [BK-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree). They are a specific datastructure to hold metric information. Your metric needs to be a genuine metric (in the mathematical sense of the word). But that's easily arranged.